# close button with fixed positition not showing in safari (sidr menu)

Tags: html, css, button, safari, sidr

I am using the jquery plugin sidr to display pop windows, that all have a close button in the top corner overlaid on top of an image.

to keep the button in place I was using the css attribute:

```
position: fixed;
```

which works in chrome, but in FF the close button show up in the wrong place and in Safari it doesnt show up at all.
changing it to:

```
position: absolute;
```

fixed the problem in FF but the button still doesn't show in Safari.
with

```
position: relative;
```

the button shows but is then no longer in its correct position.

Help on resolving this issue would be much appreciated! 
Below is the full code.

html button:

```
<button id="close" type="button" onclick="$.sidr('close', 'blago');">X</button>
```

CSS:

```
    #close{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    margin: 15px;
    background: #000;
    background-color: Transparent;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Addition: if I put the button outside of the sidr div it does show up, any idea of wht the problem could be?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, 
The problem was that `left: 0;` was not defined which apparently was needed for safari to diplay it in its correct position.